# Prevent passing keydown event from control to parent form?

Tags: c#

I have a C#/.Net form with several controls. On all the controls the keydown events should be passed to the parent form except one.

Is there any way to prevent a specific control from passing such events?

Comment: What does "C#/.Net form" mean? WinForms? WebForms? WPF? ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Events can't be passed between objects.  Events aren't objects in C#.

Comment: A Form's overridden `ProcessCmdKey` method is called before the `Form.KeyDown` event (when you have set `[Form].KeyPreview = True`), if that's what you mean. The Message `m.HWnd` returns the handle of the control that notified the event. You can then see whether it's the control you want ignored and *signal* not to take action. But, your description is not exactly verbose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
Public Class MyControl
    Inherits WhatEverControl 'For example TextBox

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
          return false 'This control wont allow keydown events pass to the parent form
    End Function
End Class
```